# Once we select item from the dropdownlist, that particular item must be removed from the all previous dropdownlist in the grid view on row databound

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, dropdown

I have dropdown list in one of gridview column and once i select value from dropdown list, It should be removed from other dropdownlist i.eprevious and next dropdown list. As this value is already assigned, so it should not available for other dropdowns (previous and next dropdown inside gridview).

For incoming dropdown list in gridview, i achived using below code.

```
                List<int> roles = null;
                int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
                roles = new List<int>();
                for (int i=1;i<=index;i++)
                {
                    GridViewRow prevRow = grdUserProvision.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - i];
                    ddlSelectedRole = prevRow.FindControl("ddlRole") as DropDownList;
                    roles.Add(Convert.ToInt32( ddlSelectedRole.SelectedValue));

                }
                foreach (var fileterRoles in roles)
                {
                    _roles.RemoveAll(x=>x.RoleID == fileterRoles);
                }
                ControlUtilities.BindListWithSelect(ddlRole, _roles);
```

But how to remove items from previous dropdown inside gridview?

Answer (score 0):

What cute question!

So, before we write code, lets layout a way to approach this probelm

So, the logic for this will be:

Get grid data list  (don’t file  the gv just yet)

Get full dropdown data list of choices
(with existing choices removed)

Then: bind gridview
For each row,

Dropdown list choices = “current selection” + available drop downs.

So, above quite much is the solution and logic we need.

So, let's assume that we have a list of people, and each user can ONLY select one Hotel from a list of hotels (I just happen to have that data handy – but the problem will/would/is much the same for any such data. (a grid of choices, each row with a drop down list of some choices).

So, this code works:

```
Dim rstHotels As New DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT People.ID, FirstName, LastName, City, Hotel_ID, HotelName
        FROM People
        LEFT JOIN tblHotelsL ON tblHotelsL.ID = Hotel_ID
         ORDER BY FirstName"
    Dim rstGrid As DataTable = Myrst(strSQL)

    strSQL =
        "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA 
        WHERE ID NOT IN 
            (SELECT Hotel_ID FROM People WHERE Hotel_ID IS NOT NULL)"

    rstHotels = Myrst(strSQL)
    GridView1.DataSource = rstGrid
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Above loads up GV and our data.

and we need code to load up the combo box (drop down list) for each row.

That code is this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        Dim MyDropDown As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("cboHotels")

        ' set combo box choices
        MyDropDown.DataSource = rstHotels
        MyDropDown.DataBind()
        MyDropDown.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please select", "0"))

        ' now add current choice to drop down (if exist)
        With gData
            If Not IsDBNull(.Item("Hotel_ID")) Then
                MyDropDown.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem(.Item("HotelName"), .Item("Hotel_ID")))
                MyDropDown.SelectedIndex = 1
            End If
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

So, we now see/get this.

Note how as I select values for the last 4 rows, the choices go away from the combo box.

[image]

and we auto save (auto post-back), so our save back to database code is this:

```
Sub SaveData()
    Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY FirstName"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            For Each gRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
                Dim cbo As DropDownList = gRow.FindControl("cboHotels")
                If cbo.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                    rstData.Rows(gRow.RowIndex).Item("Hotel_ID") = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    rstData.Rows(gRow.RowIndex).Item("Hotel_ID") = cbo.SelectedItem.Value
                End If
            Next

            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```